# Google Analytics add custom click event to in-page view

Tags: click, google-analytics, tracking

I've added the '_trackEvent' onclick function to all of my outbound links on my webpage and Analytics is tracking the events just fine.  The problem is that the clicks don't show up on the in-page view - the one which shows click % - which is a feature I'd like to track.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Google Analytics can only track content that reports to the GA account (UA) that is configured, even if the external pages that your links point to have GA installed, it won´t show on your in-page analytics.

The in-page Analytics report show the percentage based on the amount of pageviews of the pages that any links point to, inside your domain, so no outbound links.

If your´re really interested in analysing the percentage of clicks in a specific button, you could change your _trackEvent method to id the button in someway.

Find more about [_trackEvent](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEventTracking.html)
Find more about [In-Page Analytics](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178902)

Augusto Roselli
Web Analytics - Google Certified
[dp6.com.br](http://www.dp6.com.br)

Comment: Is it just that the in-page is arbitrarily restricted to pageviews within the domain or is it that the external links aren't responding somehow?  I already use the _trackEvent but it tracks events...it doesn't report the clicks in the in-page.  Do I have to register a pageview manually instead of - or in conjunction with the event?

Comment: Yes, the in-page analytics is restricted to your domain only, think of it as a crawler, that analyses your pages and the links that lead to them, then it cross-checks with the pageviews for each page and shows you the percentage on the buttons. External links don´t go to any page with pageviews for your account, so they wont show up. You could do the same by hand, checking the relation of pageviews on the page that contains the links and the events triggered.